# Installed packages in docker image not found in path?

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile for custom image with Gradle and Node installed:

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy

LABEL key=DevOps

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-i", "-c"]

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install curl -y 

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash

RUN source /root/.bashrc && nvm install 12.14.1

RUN nvm install 12.20.0

RUN apt install zip unzip

RUN curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

RUN sdk install java 8.0.302-open

RUN sdk install gradle 3.4.1

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

CMD [ "bin/bash" ]
```

After I run it, it says that npm is not found in $PATH, I tried Java, Gradle as well but they weren't found in the path as well.

I don't know why since I installed them as you can tell from the Dockerfile.

How can I preinstall these dependencies so that I can address them during the build process of my app?

Comment: probably nvm had installed npm for root user, while during build you use an other user, if this is the case, you should install your tool globally.

Comment: @lety I specify during the build to use the root user, so that shouldn't really be a problem in my opinion.

Comment: ok, in my case I build docker image with root and than run container and build my software with jenkins user and npm was not found. Probably here there is an other issue

Comment: @lety Can you share your Dockerfile? Maybe I missed setting up something.

Comment: here is: RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install wget 
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash && . $HOME/.bashrc && echo $PATH && nvm install v10.24.1

Comment: to get npm available to other users: RUN . $HOME/.bashrc && n=$(dirname $(which node)) && chmod -R 755 $n && cp -r $n /usr/local && cp -r $n/../lib /usr/local && cp -r $n/../share /usr/local

Comment: did you try to put "USER root" after FROM ubuntu:jammy? or "RUN echo $HOME" to see if it is root user that build your image?

Comment: What application are you developing that needs two different versions of Node plus a JVM, all to run the same program?  Can you split it into multiple images, with one image per language or component, without needing a version manager like `nvm` or `sdk`?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried that at first, for example, I installed only node in an image and ran it, but it still showed me that npm wasn't found in $PATH, so I figured I should put all of my dependencies into one image and figure out how to add them to $PATH so they could be referenced during the build process.

Comment: As @RichardRublev suggested initially, it can be easier to start an image `FROM node:12.14.1` which will have `npm` preinstalled.